# Debian 8 Mute Audio on Intel NUC

Tags: debian, drivers, audio, intel

I cannot get sound output on my Debian 8 install despite signs of intel audio drivers loaded properly.
Monitor volume is up and audio works fine booting up from an Ubuntu 16 USB, so the hardware seems supported.
Under Debian 8, I've performed basic troubleshooting, ensuring no mutes enabled and ensuring correct output is selected.
I've tried Steve Litt's guide; while educational, no success:
http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/sound/sound_troubleshooting.htm

My hardware:
`Intel Corporation BOXNUC6I7KYK4`

Command output:

```
# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l

# uname -a
Linux Debbie 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lspci -s 00:1f.3 -v
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a170 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2064
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 141
    Memory at dc240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at dc220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

# lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45118  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    67168  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    63181  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          26407  10 
snd_hda_controller     26646  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         104500  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              13148  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                88662  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_timer              26614  1 snd_pcm
snd                    65244  26 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
soundcore              13026  2 snd,snd_hda_codec

# modprobe snd_hda_intel  <<no output>>
```

Running `pavucontrol` shows the HDMI output devices and with signs that sound is being processed (the sound level bar in the Output Devices tab fluctuates as `speaker-test` outputs test noise).

I'm at a loss as to what else I need to do to get sound output audible so your help is much appreciated. Do let me know if I have left out any details required to resolve this.

Comment: What is the output of `modprobe snd-hda-intel` ?

Comment: Both `modprobe snd-hda-intel` and `modprobe snd_hda_intel` result in no output.

Answer (score -1):

I succeeded with this several times:

`sudo alsactl init`

Comment: This answer is not very useful without an explanation of how and/or why this command works. I'd suggest that you [edit] the answer to include such an explanation.

Comment: OK. But...English is not my native language, but I'm not going to use Google translate. And you're right, I shall not give hire any more advice.